# How do I log in to the ubuntu 10.04 server using grub2 from a remote computer/terminal with GUI running

Tags: ubuntu, login, graphical-user-interface, grub2

I upgraded my server from ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04. It now uses the grub2 bootloader. In 8.04 from the grub log-in page I could select the option log in to server and thereby connect through SSH directly to my server and have the GUI running. I can currently log in to my upgraded server now from any of my 8.04 machines using grub1 with the GUI running. I cannot log in that way from a machine that uses grub2 and ubuntu 10.04. I want to upgrade my entire network to ubuntu 10.04 but cannot until I know how to log in to the network from grub2 with the gui open. I have exhausted all my ideas as to the solution to this problem. Any help would be most appreciated. Thank-you

Comment: Are you talking about grub or gdm?

Comment: I am talking about opening gdm from grub2 using SSH from a client. In the original grub I did the following after starting linux Options>Select Session> Secure Remote Connection A popup would appear <Enter Hostname> followed by <Enter Password>

Answer (score -1):

The answer came from realizing some new features included in ubuntu 10.04 for remote desktop access. You do not need to log in to the server at boot up using grub 2 any more. You can select **Applications>Internet>Remote Desktop Viewer** to access your server using vnc or ssh. However, after exploraton I prefer the following. Open a terminal on the client. Access the server in the following way. **You@clientcomputer:~$ssh -X servername** and provide your password if necessary. The -X modifier allows one to run gui based software. Once you are on the command line for the server simply run the software you want. For example, **nautilus** will open your navigation. From there, you can navigate to the desktop and run your application. This is a better approach that I used before. Now I have access to the gui on the server and local computer at the same time, plus the ability to use the command line on both. I hope this answer to my own question helps someone else out there.

Comment: Like your question, your answer barely makes any sense. I mean, sure, you can do all of those things, but they're a) nothing out of the ordinary and b) nothing to do with the grub bootloader.